# Filter get invoke twice in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a filter which extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

In security config class I have below,

```
  @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(getMyFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(getMyFilter2(), MyFilter.class);
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll();
    }

    private MyFilter getMyFilter() {
        return new MyFilter(properties, apiConsumer);
    }
```

When I invoke an REST endpoint with postman, the `doFilter` method of `MyFilter` get hits twice. In both time it has the same `requestedSessionId` and `strippedServletPath` in the `ServletRequest`.

But `MyFilter2` which extend `GenericFilterBean`, only get invoke once.

The order of filter execution is `MyFilter.doFilter` -> `MyFilter2.doFilter` -> `MyFilter.doFilter`

What would be the reason and how can I find the root cause?

Comment: I had defined the MyFilter with @Component annotation. When I remove that annotation, It hits only once

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this behaviour appears only on first request (when basic authentication popup window appears). If so, then this is because basic authentication specification and it's implementation in Spring's `BasicAuthenticationFilter`.

When you invoke your service for the first time, Spring looks for `Authorization` header on your request, and if it's not present, it sends response with `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header to your browser. 
When your browser receives this response with that particular header, it shows authentication popup. When you type your user and password your browser makes another request (now with appropriate `Authorization` header) and now Spring can properly authorize your request.

The problem is that during that whole process Spring is processing filter chain twice (on every request).

You can read more about Basic Authentication here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Thanks but I am using postman to invoke the request. I dont get such authentication popup.

Comment: If you are using postman and it's `Basic Auth` authorization, then it will work the same way (postman handles this multistep authentication process itself)

Comment: How does your example controller look like?

Comment: I have @RequestMapping with GET and  @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('student')") annotations

Comment: Even without @PreAuthorize annotation, the behaviour is same

Comment: Does this multiple invocation appears on every request? Or it happens only on the first request after restart? Have you tried requesting your api multiple times after server start?

Comment: Well I had defined the MyFilter with @Component annotation. When I remove that annotation, It hits only once.